# Remove or hide search box from SharePoint Online Modern experience communication HUB

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hub-site

I am rebuilding a SharePoint online site using the Modern Experience and I have started building it out with a communication HUB as the parent site to leverage Mega Menus. The company requirement is to remove OR hide the search box that appears on top the communication HUB page by default. How can I do this as I have found no documentation on the Microsoft Community Sites and elsewhere.
[image]

Comment: That is a kinda strange requirement as that search box provides a hub scoped search option

Comment: The short answer is you can't do.  It is not supported.  There are hacks which will break without any notification and will be hard to maintain so avoid them unless there is a supported way from Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this can be achieved by Powershell script. Here you go.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/[site]" -UseWebLogin
try{
 $web = Get-PnPWeb
 #0 - Inherit, #1 - AllPages, #2 - ModernOnly, #3 - Hidden enums for Global (Modern Search)
 $web.SearchBoxInNavBar=3
 $web.Update()
 Invoke-PnPQuery
 Write-Host "Done" -BackgroundColor Green   
}
catch{
 Write-Host "No permission" -BackgroundColor Red    
}
Write-Host "All Done"
```

Hope, that may solve your query. Ahh, its been long time since this question posted. Maybe someone else will find it useful.

Comment: Does this solution remove the search bar forall sites in the site collection or just the landing page?

Answer (score 2):

Use below:

```
Set-PnPSearchSettings -SearchBoxInNavBar Hidden -Scope Site
```

Ref - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpsearchsettings?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has recently moved the search box to the Office suite bar to create an uniform search experience for most of the Office products, and their documentation might not be updated on how to customize it. In fact, there are still pending items in their Roadmap, which will bring more custom functionality in Search when deployed.

For your particular requirement, I can think of using CSS style to hide the search bar. i.e. pick the class that Search box is using and then set 'visible:false' to it. Now, to inject such styles in SharePoint modern pages, you will have to make use of SharePoint Framework Extensions application customizer.

Using the customizer, you can inject a CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) file to your modern page, which can essentially override the styles of the page and provide you with required look and feel. Please check [this article from wordpress](https://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2019/05/03/change-styles-in-sharepoint-online-modern-pages/) where I have explained and provided detailed steps on how you can use SharePoint Framework Application customizer to brand your SharePoint modern pages by injecting custom CSS files.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Note that CSS removal would not be a supported solution as modifying the Suite Nav in any way is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom CSS style and inject the CSS on modern pages using SPFx extensions to achieve it.

The following solution with source code for your reference.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

To hide the search box, we can use CSS code below:

```
#O365_SearchBoxContainer{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't work. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

LZ_MSFT has it right.

#O365_SearchBoxContainer{
display:none !important;
}

HOWEVER Microsoft changes the names at any given time.
Currently it is :
O365_SearchBoxContainer_container

Use F12 on your browser to find out.