# Remove or hide search box from SharePoint Online - For only one page - the landing Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, top-link-bar

Is it possible to remove/hidesearch box from SharePoint Online - For only one page the landing Page.
I know you can use pnp-powershell script but it seems that removes it for the whole site collection?
What are my options to remove just on the landing page?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom CSS style and inject the CSS on modern pages using SPFx extensions to achieve it.

The following solution with source code for your reference.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264713/remove-or-hide-search-box-from-sharepoint-online-modern-experience-communication)

To hide the search box, we can use CSS code below:

```
#O365_SearchBoxContainer{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not supported by Microsoft.